# Programmatically create special Polymer-Element

Tags: custom-controls, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have got a polymer-element with following html:

```dart
<polymer-element name="tab-bar">
  <template>
    <button>Hello</button>
    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <div>This element is {{ item }}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="tab_bar.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The underlying dart class looks as follows:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('tab-bar')
class TabBar extends PolymerElement {
  List items;

  TabBar(List<String> items) {
    this.items = toObservable(items);
  }
}
```

With the following approach, it isn't possible to programmatically add the element:

```dart
query('body').children.add(createElement(new TabBar(['One','Two','Three'])));
```

So now, how can I add such a polymer element programatically and also set the list in the constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of polymer 0.8.5 you can use constructor like

```
new Element.tag('tag-bar');
```

also, no more .xtag and no more .host (host == this now)

credits go to [Seth Ladd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123471/seth-ladd)  who explained this on polymer mailing list

Comment: I've tried using this code and it only adds the `<tag-bar>` element to the DOM, but it does not actually render de HTML inside the template tag of the polymer element, any clues on why this is happening?

Comment: Triztian I have the same problem.

Comment: Ahh I had to import my component first, I forgot. in my main html I had to <link rel="import" href="component/drop-menu.html">

Answer (score 3):

Note: this only works for polymer.dart < 0.8.5. See other answer for the new way.

Custom elements don't really have constructors like we're familiar with them in Dart. Instead, try this:

```
var tabBar = createElement('tag-bar');
tabBar.xtag.items = toObservable(['a','b','c']);

query('body').children.add(tabBar);
```