# Programmatic custom element broken in dart polymer 0.9.5?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

The [earlier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548360/3433148) for programmatic custom element creation in polymer 0.8.5 seems to be broken in polymer 0.9.5.

If we modify the [standard click-counter example](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/#data-binding) to use programmatic element creation, like so:

```dart
main() {
  Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {   
    print('${rec.loggerName}: ${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
  });

  initPolymer();

  var clickCounter = new Element.tag('click-counter');     
  document.body.children.add(clickCounter);
}
```

the on-click events *are* correctly invoking the {{increment}} method, but the {{count}} value is not updated in the HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymer querySelector working on DartVM but not in Chrome after compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932180/polymer-queryselector-working-on-dartvm-but-not-in-chrome-after-compile)

Comment: another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer code should be run from

```dart
import "package:polymer/polymer.dart";

main() {
  initPolymer().run(() {
    // code here works most of the time
    Polymer.onReady.then((value) {     
      // some things must wait until onReady callback is called
      // for an example look at the discussion linked below
    });
  });
}
```

[simple tooltip working in dartium, not as javascript](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/7cRLZerHmOo/v9eCBSP0-lYJ)